# What is the meaning of self driving car

Tags: gerunds

Do they mean the cars that we have to drive ourself

Or do they mean the cars that drive automatically by themself?

Answer (score 1):

**Self-driving** car means that the operation does not require human interaction.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_car):

> An autonomous car (also known as a driverless car, auto, self-driving car, robotic car) is a vehicle that is capable of sensing its environment and navigating without human input.

Answer (score 0):

A "self-driving" car drives itself using computer technology.

A "self-drive" car is a car offered for hire without a driver. The customer is expected to drive it himself. Example: "U-Drive is a UK van rental, van hire and self-drive car rental company." (https://www.u-drive.co.uk/about-udrive)